# Dark Souls 2 scholar of the first sin repetitive growling bug

Tags: steam, dark-souls-2

In Dark Souls Scholar of the first sin. I have progressed to the shaded ruins when I reach the male scorpions den and went inside and fought the duo wielding swordsman I kept hearing this strange growling sound.

After I killed him and progressed through the area the sound continues at 5-7 second intervals for some reason it doesn't occur in Majula but where ever I go in game new areas, old areas and even areas with no enemies the sound continues.

It's getting really annoying because it drowns out other sounds that are really important like ticking from traps, skeletons shambling together, footsteps of a baddie running up behind me etc etc.

Does anyone know how to remove this?

I am playing on steam with a windows 7 PC.

Comment: Are you wearing the ring of whispers?  http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/ring-of-whispers

Comment: I was when I talked to the scorpion guy but I took it off after I beat Najika.

Comment: Wow I actually had it on this entire time. I took it off and restarted my pc played for about a half hour and no longer heard the sound. Thanks Xerido!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well As posted in my comment.

If you used the Ring of Whispers  [darksouls2.wikidot.com/ring-of-whispers](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/ring-of-whispers)
to talk to Manscorpion Tark and didn't take it of, one of the effects is whenever is an enemy near you will hear the sounds you describe